# Protocol in property, error Protocol can only be used as a generic constraint

Tags: ios, swift, generics, solid

I'm trying to make an inheritance generic case and i've been done in Dart and it worked like this:

```
// DART
class Car<T> implements Vehicle<T> {
  EngineInterface? engine;
  StorageInterface<T> storage;
 
  Car({
    required this.engine,
    required this.storage,
  });
}
```

but when i try to make in Swift, it a little bit different:

[image]

The error is

> Protocol 'StorageProtocol' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements

Here is my other code:

```
protocol Vehicle {
    associatedtype T
    
    func accelerate() -> String
    func brake() -> String
    func refill(source: T) -> String
}

protocol StorageProtocol {
    associatedtype T
    
    func fill(source: T) -> String
    func getSource() -> T
}
```

I tried to refactor the code like this:

```
class Car<T>: Vehicle where T : StorageProtocol {
    
    var engine: EngineProtocol
    var storage: T
    
    init(engine: EngineProtocol, storage: T) {
        self.engine = engine
    }
    
    func accelerate() -> String {
        return ""
    }
    
    func brake() -> String {
        return ""
    }
    
    func refill(source: T.T) -> String {
        storage.fill(source: source)
    }
}
```

but, i have to change the Car's generic

```
let petrolEngine = PetrolEngine()
let tank = Tank()
let car = Car<Tank>(
    engine: petrolEngine, storage: tank
)
car.refill(source: Oil())
```

instead of use Oil inside Car generic

```
let car = Car<Oil>(
    engine: petrolEngine, storage: tank
)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=can+only+be+used+as+a+generic+constraint+because+it+has+Self+or+associated+type+requirements

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution,
that we have to make alias and add where clause in generic context

```
class Car<TypeAlias, EngineAlias: EngineProtocol, StorageAlias: StorageProtocol> : Vehicle
where StorageAlias.T == TypeAlias, EngineAlias.T == TypeAlias {

typealias T = TypeAlias

var engine: EngineAlias
var storage: StorageAlias

init(engine: EngineAlias, storage: StorageAlias) {
    self.engine = engine
    self.storage = storage
}

func accelerate() -> String {
    return "▶️ \(engine.move()) -> Engine Move"
}

func brake() -> String {
    return "⏹ Braked"
}

func refill(source: T) -> String {
    let fillTheStorage = storage.fill(source: source)
    return " \(fillTheStorage)"
}
}
```

reference: [Generic Where Clause](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Generics.html#:%7E:text=Generic%20Where%20Clauses,-Type%20constraints%2C%20as&text=It%20can%20also%20be%20useful,types%20must%20be%20the%20same.)